# Prime number finder,finds 6 more primes than it should

Tags: c

I'm new to programming and i cant seem to find the mistake that makes my program find 6 more primes than it should.The correct answer for the given range is 904533.

In addition,the first printf used seems not to work, and the suggested program run time is around 5 seconds while mine is around 8.

Hope someone could help me, thank you in advance.

```
#define MINNUM 3990000000
#define MAXNUM 4010000000
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int  r, j, i, checker, k, primecount = 0, d, d_save;  //
    unsigned int a;
    unsigned long long res = 1;

    printf("Checking range [3990000000,4010000000] for primes...");

    for (k = MINNUM + 1; k <= MAXNUM - 2; k += 2)
    {
        checker = 0;
        if (k % 3 != 0)
        {
            d = k - 1;         // Reset variables
            res = 1;
            r = 0;
            //Create (2^r)*d= n-1

            while (d % 2 == 0) {
                r++;
                d /= 2;
            }
            //printf("%u can be written as : (2^%d)*%llu\n",k-1,r,d);   

            d_save = d; //saves d for each j loop

            do {

                for (j = 1; j <= 3; j++)
                {
                    d = d_save;

                    res = 1;
                    if (j == 1) a = 2;
                    if (j == 2) a = 7;
                    if (j == 3) a = 61;

                    //Calculate a^d mod k
                    while (d > 0)
                    {
                        // When y is odd 
                        if (d & 1)
                            res = (res*a) % k;

                        // When y is even 
                        d = d >> 1;       //Same as y = y/2 
                        a = (a*a) % k;

                    }

                    //Miller Rabin's c
                    if (res == 1 || res == k - 1) { checker = 1; continue; }

                    while (r != 0)
                    {

                        res = (res * res) % k;


                        if (res == 1) { checker = 0;  break; }

                        if (res == k - 1) { checker = 1; break; }

                        r--;
                    }


                }
            } while (checker == 1);

            //printf("check %u %d\n",k,checker);
            if (checker == 1) primecount++;
        }
    }
    printf("primes are %u", primecount);
}
```

Comment: i fixed it for you, but please properly intend your code next time you ask.

Comment: How is the `<= MAXNUM - 2` correct?! It specifically leaves the odd number `MAXNUM -1` out.

Comment: BTW, do not declare the variables at the beginning of the function but always just before the actual use in the innermost block possible. I was certain that `a` was being uninitialized, which is not the case, but it is very hard to track. C does not require that the variables be defined in the beginning of **function** - it **never has**. Furthermore you're using `//` for comments which means that your compiler cannot be strict C89

Comment: "makes my program find 6 more primes than it should." more is better, i gues ... usually?

Answer (score 1):

**Overflow**

In 3 places code does something like `(a*a) % k`.  The multiplication overflows 32-bit `unsigned` math

Replace with `(1ULL* a*a) % k`.  That will not overflow for the values used in OP's code.

**Incorrect application of the algorithm**

The [Miller–Rabin primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) as used by OP does does not use the original `r` is the 3 `j` iterations.

```
            unsigned orignal_r = r;  // added
            d_save = d; //saves d for each j loop
            do {
                for (j = 1; j <= 3; j++)
                {
                    r = orignal_r; // added
                    d = d_save;
```

The default should be

```
       // checker = 0;
       checker = 1;
```

3 is not a special case

```
       // if (k % 3 != 0)
       if (1)
```

Before the `while()`, set checker to false;

```
            checker = 0; // add
            while (r != 0)
```

After the `while()`, test `checker`

```
            } // end while (r != 0)
            // add
            if (checker == 0) {
              break;
            }
```

Rather than iterate based on `checker`, iterate once.

```
        // } while (checker == 1);
        } while (0);
```

With these changes, the correct answer appeared.

There may exist other issues.  Hence the [@Antoine Mathys good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53354741/2410359) that spins off the prime test as a function is *much* easier to code, follow and improve.

**Unclear limit**

The `- 2` in the loop is unclear.  It appears to come from the *Miller–Rabin* algorithm, yet that is for odd `k` and `MINNUM` is not constrained to even.

```
// for (k = MINNUM + 1; k <= MAXNUM - 2; k += 2)
// Could use `| 1` to insure `k` starts at odd
for (k = MINNUM | 1; k <= MAXNUM; k += 2)
```

---

The below is now simple now some research

Via another algorithm, the count should be 904533.

The first false prime counted is 3991124341.  I suspect determining that error will explain the others.

```
False prime 3991124341 = 33769 * 118189
False prime 3992697997 = 137 * 3061 * 9521
False prime 3997536427 = 19267 * 207481
False prime 3999921383 = 18787 * 212909
False prime 4002510817 = 223 * 2887 * 6217
False prime 4002592133 = 36527 * 109579
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback.I have totally made some goofy mistakes.Though,i still dont get why my algorithm finda 6 more numbera as primes.I found the pseudocode version of this algorithm via wikipedia,searching about miller rabins primality test.I would be really grateful if you could find the mistake in my code.

Comment: @ΔημήτρηςΣπανάκης  Please carefully re-check that the code posted is your true code.

Comment: @ΔημήτρηςΣπανάκης The mistake is not in the code so much as in what you expect it to do.

Comment: @ΔημήτρηςΣπανάκης For a robust `powmod()` see [Modular exponentiation without range restriction](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/187257/29485).

Comment: @chux, Miller-Rabin is an exact primality test under some circumstances, and the OP appears to have satisfied those.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Agreed. Answer re-written.

Answer (score 0):

I won't give you the full code, you'll have to work a little to fill in the blanks.

First if you have something like this

```
unsigned int a, b, c, d;
a = (b * c) % k;
```

replace it with

```
unsigned int a, b, c, d;
a = (1ULL * b * c) % k;
```

Functions are your friend. You can structure the whole program like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MINNUM 3990000000U
#define MAXNUM 4010000000U

// calculate a^d mod k                                                          
unsigned int exp_mod (unsigned int a, unsigned int d, unsigned int k)
{
    ...
}

// assume 1 < k < 4759123141
// assume k odd
// return true iff k is prime
bool miller_test (unsigned int k)
{
    // calculate d and r such that k - 1 = (2^r) * d, with d odd                
    unsigned int d, r;
    ...

    const unsigned int a[3] = { 2, 7, 61 };
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        if (k == a[j]) {
            return true;
        }

        unsigned int res = exp_mod (a[j], d, k);

        if (res == 1 || res == (k - 1)) {
            continue;
        }

        bool composite = true;
        for (unsigned int s = 1; s < r; s++) {
            res = (1ULL * res * res) % k;
            if (res == k - 1) {
                composite = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (composite) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

int main ()
{
    ...
}
```